# JqGrid not able to fill itself from Json response

Tags: jqgrid

So I have a javascript function that runs on page load, listed below:

```
function createGrid()
        {
            var myGrid = 
                jQuery("#responseMessages"),
                reportBtn = "<input style='height:22px;width:100px;' type='button' value='Report' />",
                getColumnIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
                    var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
                    for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++) {
                        if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                            return i; // return the index
                        }
                    }
                    return -1;
            };

            myGrid.jqGrid({
                url: "<%= Url.Action("GetMessages", "Home") %>",
                datatype: 'json',
                myType: 'GET',
                height: 'auto',
                colModel: [
                    { name:'distance', index:'distance', label:'Distance', width:100 },
                    { name:'age', index:'age', label:'Age', width:75 },
                    { name:'message', index:'message', label:'Message', width:500 },
                    { name:'messageId', index:'messageId', key:true, hidden:true },
                    { name:'report', index:'report', label: 'Report', width:100,
                        formatter:function() { return reportBtn; } }
                ],
                loadComplete: function() {
                    var i=getColumnIndexByName(myGrid,'report');
                    // nth-child need 1-based index so we use (i+1) below
                    $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(i+1)+") > input",myGrid[0]).click(function(e) {
                        var tr=$(e.target,myGrid[0].rows).closest("tr.jqgrow");
                        var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to report this message?")
                        if (x)
                        {
                            reportMessage(tr[0].id);
                        }
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                },
                rowNum:25,
                viewrecords:true, 
                rowList:[10,25,50],
                pager: '#pager',
                caption: "What's going on in your area!"
            });
        }
```

Now it loads the grid fine, actually makes a call to the `public ActionResult GetMessages()` on the server correctly, and doesn't receive any data from the response, so it doesn't fill the grid and says there are no records. Yay!

Problem is, I click a button on the page, which triggers this javascript method:

```
function reloadGrid()
        {
            $("#responseMessages").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
```

So the grid goes and re-gets the server method, yay! But this time, the server sends a response back that looks like this from firebug:

```
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":{"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"id":3,"cell":["\u003c 1 mile","25 hour(s)","sdfgsdfgsdfg","3"]},{"id":2,"cell":["\u003c 1 mile","25 hour(s)","adfg","2"]}],"total":1},"JsonRequestBehavior":1}
```

However, the grid doesn't fill and still says there are no records, when there should be 3.

Comment: I am not sure that you know the rule which you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer. In many statistics the accepted answers without voting will not calculated (not included in the "total score"). One not interpret the answer as helpful. You just closed the question. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46795/why-are-accepted-answers-not-included-in-the-tag-badge-calculation/) you can read how one interpret the "total score".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use not standard format of JSON data, so you should include the corresponding [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) parameter in the jqGrid which describe how jqGrid should get the data from the JSON input:

```
jsonReader: {
    page: "Data.page",
    total: "Data.total",
    records: "Data.records",
    root: "Data.rows"
}
```

How you can read from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Scott.htm) the data will be read after the change.